# Which software is the best to test websites across multiple devices?

Tags: testing, cross-browser, web, dotnetnuke

I have got a DNN website and would like to test the site on multiple devices. I currently use Google Chrome, but it is not always as accurate. Is it possible to use Xamarin Test Cloud or any other software? My company do not want to spend money on a Device Board.

Comment: hi Tig7r, the reason you are getting downvotes is that this site is about code problems and this site also avoids questions which can be considered "opinion" based.  You need to post code, what you tried and what does not work.  I would suggest asking this question on the https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ site.  Best of luck
ps. chrome does have limited device emulation https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-simulate-mobile-devices-with-device-mode-in-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried https://www.browserstack.com.

It allows you to test the site across many devices and browsers but it does have some limitations. It only gives you a screenshot of the page and the page must be publicly view-able.